# Is there a way to extract the column label for the root node in Spark 2.1.3 mllib (Scala) decision tree classifier model?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I'm currently working on a dataset that requires a decision tree classification. The DataFrame I have created is a SparseVector using the example from [mllib example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/ml-classification-regression.html#decision-tree-classifier). I know there is a way to extract the impurity and prediction for the root node, however, I want to be able to get the column name of this node.

Assume my DataFrame looks like this:

```
+-----|-------|-------|-------+
| id  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+-----|-------|-------|-------+
| 0   | 1.0   | 0.0   | 2.0   |
| 1   | 2.0   | 1.0   | 0.0   |
| 3   | 2.0   | 2.0   | 1.0   |
+-----|-------|-------|-------+
```

My final dataset has many more columns than this but just to show an example of what I am working with.

Then I use transform this to into a VectorIndexer using the example code which would give me something similar to this:

```
+-----|--------------------------------+
| id  | features                       | 
+-----|--------------------------------+
| 0   | (3, [0, 2], [1.0, 2.0])        |
| 1   | (3, [0, 1]. [2.0, 1.0])        |
| 3   | (3, [0, 1, 2], [2.0, 2.0, 1.0] | 
+-----|--------------------------------+
```

At the end of it all, I have my learned classification tree and I can get the root node from the tree. But what I want to do is get the column name associated with the root node.

```
val data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("./src/main/resources/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
  .fit(data)

val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setMaxCategories(4) // features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
  .fit(data)

val (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")

val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol("prediction")
  .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
  .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)


val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureIndexer, dt, labelConverter))
println("Pipeline stages: ")
pipeline.getStages.foreach(println)

val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

val treeModel = model.stages(2).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeClassificationModel]
println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + treeModel.toDebugString)

val root = treeModel.rootNode
println("Root: " + root.toString)
```

This would give me something for example:

```
Trained classification tree model:
DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=dtc_5eadf281a5fc) of depth 4 with 13 nodes
  If (feature 32 in {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0})
   If (feature 4 in {0.0})
    Predict: 2.0
   Else (feature 4 not in {0.0})
    Predict: 1.0
  Else (feature 32 not in {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0})
   If (feature 37 in {0.0,2.0})
    If (feature 1 in {1.0})
     Predict: 1.0
    Else (feature 1 not in {1.0})
     If (feature 4 in {0.0,3.0})
      Predict: 0.0
     Else (feature 4 not in {0.0,3.0})
      Predict: 2.0
   Else (feature 37 not in {0.0,2.0})
    If (feature 3 in {0.0})
     Predict: 2.0
    Else (feature 3 not in {0.0})
     Predict: 1.0

Root: InternalNode(prediction = 0.0, impurity = 0.6428571428571429, split = org.apache.spark.ml.tree.CategoricalSplit@a0058edd)
```

As you can see I can see the root from the tree is `feature 32` but I want to be able to get the column name for it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Based on your dataset what will be column name for `feature 32`? Can you add realistic dataset, for which you wanna try out.